# Sending product to backend without cart for order quotation?

Tags: php

I have created a product and i want to remove its price instead i want to label it as "Ask quotation" then i want to send this product to backend as order but without shopping cart, is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

This is kind of a broad subject. I doubt you will get a full working solution, but I can give you some ideas.

First of all you have to make the product out of stock so it cannot be added to the cart.
Then add a new yes/no attribute for all the products. let's call it 'for_quotation'.
And in frontend if the value of `$_product->getForQuotation() == 1` then display a button 'Ask for quotation' and hide the price.
When that button is clicked open a popup form (or a new page but I thing that popup is less intrusive) where the user fills in the basic data and submits it. The result should be sent by email and/or stored in a table. If you choose to store the quotation requests in a table you need an admin CRUD module where the admin can view the requests and take different actions.

Answer (score 0):

I think you will have to be very careful with this. Changing the price in all your core files and adding something there would drive magento nuts as the products price attribute is involved in many calculation/sanitizing/validation processes of the Magento core modules.

The only other two options I can think of would be

1. using out of stock and then a custom out of stock message which would say that the product is not out of stock and you have to enquire for the price. By this it would also be able to leave the customers email address as a contact.
2. the other option would be one of the extensions available for this
   https://amasty.com/magento-call-for-price.html
   http://www.cart2quote.com/